# How to show the container in a nested treemap?

Tags: highcharts

I have a treemap made of

- a big container

  - with an element
  - with an element
  - with an element which is itself made of

    - an element
    - an element
- another big container

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  series: [{
    type: "treemap",
    animation: false,
    data: [
      // first big category
      {
        id: 'B',
        name: 'B'
      },
      {
        name: 'Anne',
        parent: 'B',
        value: 4
      }, {
        name: 'Peter',
        parent: 'B',
        value: 1
      },
      // below is a member of forst big category, but with sub-categories
      {
        name: 'aaa container',
        parent: 'B',
        id: 'aaa'
      }, {
        name: 'Anneinaaa',
        parent: 'aaa',
        value: 1
      }, {
        name: 'Rickinaaa',
        parent: 'aaa',
        value: 3
      },
      // second big category
      {
        name: 'Susanne',
        parent: 'Kiwi',
        value: 2,
        color: '#9EDE00'
      }
    ]
  }],
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/treemap.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

I would like to highlight the fact that there is a container for `Rickinaaa` and `Anneinaaa`, with a description.

Right now `Rickinaaa` and `Anneinaaa` are at the same level as `Anne` and `Peter`, despite the fact that it is their **container** (the one I do not know how to show) which should be at their level.

An example from ZingCharts which shows this multilayer presentation:

[image]

It is much easier to see the box-in-a-box structure.

**Is there a way to achieve this in Highcharts?** Specifically, how could I have a **visible** container labelled `aaa container` which would encompass the rectangles `Rickinaaa` and `Anneinaaa`

Comment: Very similar topic is answered on Highcharts forum: https://forum.highcharts.com/highcharts-usage/treemap-datalabel-design-t39579/ Let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: @KamilKulig: thank you, but I am am not sure this is the same problem. The  OP in the forum question asked about a way to separate the leafs. I am looking for a way to somehow superimpose the parent-child layers by creating an offset of the parent (so it looks like the parent encompasses (or contains) the children. This is similar to the treemap at https://datavizcatalogue.com/methods/treemap.html or https://docs.tibco.com/pub/sfire-bauthor/7.7.0/doc/html/en-US/GUID-FDA359D7-4C40-4FF3-9892-D248C6292392.html, but also further nested (more layers)

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by using **custom positioning algorithm** for treemap. The process is described here: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/treemap (*ADD YOUR OWN ALGORITHM* section).

I created simplified algorithm for demo purposes (some values are hardcoded):

```
// Custom positioning algorithm

function myFunction(parent, children) {
  childrenAreas = [];

  Highcharts.each(children, function(child) {
    // Do some calculations

    var newLeaf = null;
    if (child.id === 'A') {
      newLeaf = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 50,
        height: 50
      };
    } else if (child.id === 'B') {
      newLeaf = {
        x: 50,
        y: 0,
        width: 50,
        height: 50
      };
    } else if (child.name === 'Rick') {
      newLeaf = {
        x: parent.x + 10,
        y: parent.y + 10,
        width: parent.width - 20,
        height: (parent.height - 20) / 2
      }
    } else if (child.name === 'Peter') {
      newLeaf = {
        x: parent.x + 10,
        y: parent.y + 30,
        width: parent.width - 20,
        height: (parent.height - 20) / 2
      }
    } else if (child.name === 'Anne') {
      newLeaf = {
        x: parent.x + 10,
        y: 10,
        width: parent.width - 20,
        height: parent.height - 20
      }
    }

    if (newLeaf) {
      childrenAreas.push(newLeaf);
    }
  });
  return childrenAreas;
};

Highcharts.seriesTypes.treemap.prototype.myCustomAlgorithm = myFunction;
```

By default Highcharts assigns color `fill` attribute only for the nodes of the Highest level - all other nodes have it set to `none`. It can be changed manually via CSS:

```
.highcharts-internal-node {
  fill: #bada55
}
```

I also did a small change in the core code so that parent levels are drawn underneath the child ones:

```
(function(H) {
  var grep = H.grep,
    each = H.each,
    seriesTypes = H.seriesTypes;

  H.seriesTypes.treemap.prototype.drawPoints = function() {
    var series = this,
      points = grep(series.points, function(n) {
        return n.node.visible;
      });

    each(points, function(point) {
      var groupKey = 'level-group-' + point.node.levelDynamic;
      if (!series[groupKey]) {
        series[groupKey] = series.chart.renderer.g(groupKey)
          .attr({
            // CHANGED FROM: zIndex: 1000 - point.node.levelDynamic
            zIndex: 1000 + point.node.levelDynamic // @todo Set the zIndex based upon the number of levels, instead of using 1000
          })
          .add(series.group);
      }
      point.group = series[groupKey];

    });
    // Call standard drawPoints
    seriesTypes.column.prototype.drawPoints.call(this);



    // If drillToNode is allowed, set a point cursor on clickables & add drillId to point
    if (series.options.allowDrillToNode) {
      each(points, function(point) {
        if (point.graphic) {
          point.drillId = series.options.interactByLeaf ? series.drillToByLeaf(point) : series.drillToByGroup(point);
        }
      });
    }
  }
})(Highcharts);
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wfed4jeo/